# Xamaririn iOS app fails to attach and crashes on launch without any error

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I have a Xamarin iOS app which I was working with for a while now. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and things been pretty nice until today. Not perfect, I mean, but at least I could work with it.

And then, it happened. I built my app for iPad device aaaand.. it crashed right after launch screen without any error. I deleted my app and built it again - VSfM behaved like the app was terminated, but the app worked normally. I shut the app down, launched it from the home screen - and it crashed after launch screen. Imagine every combination of these three steps possible including cleaning and rebuilding different project versions + reinstalling VSfM and rebooting iPad - and still the same result.

However, the app behaves totally OK with the Simulator. It also doesn't crash on my other iPad but the debugger doesn't attach to the process like if it did.

Here is what I was able to get from the Console log of the device: (ARMUIIpad and com.myapp.name is for my app)

```
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash[439] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[437] ArmUIIpad
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device CommCenter[82] <Notice>: #I BundleID: <private> is no longer a foreground app
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device CommCenter[82] <Notice>: #I BundleID: <private> is no longer a foreground app
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device CommCenter[82] <Notice>: #I BundleID: <private> is no longer a foreground app
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device CommCenter[82] <Notice>: #I BundleID: <private> is no longer a foreground app
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device duetexpertd(AppPredictionInternal)[200] <Error>: No launch reason provided for launch.
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: Entry, display name com.myapp.name uuid (null) pid 437 isFront 0
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: Continue with bundle name com.myapp.name, is front 0
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: com.myapp.name: Foreground: false
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: Entry, display name com.apple.CoreAuthUI uuid 3471220A-220B-377E-A0D5-43222A865A37 pid 242 isFront 0
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: Entry, display name com.apple.CoreAuthUI uuid 3471220A-220B-377E-A0D5-43222A865A37 pid 242 isFront 0
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(MobileCoreServices)[439] <Notice>: notify_register_check() failed with error 1000000
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: NBSM Current state: normal, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: NBSM Eligible to go to broken
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[129] <Notice>: NBSM Current state: normal, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0, eligible for broken but constraints unsatisfied (0,0)
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Report of type '109(<private>)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Notice: This report is abbreviated for syslog inclusion because it could not be saved to disk.
Symbolication may be possible by manually cleaning up and including the Binary Image section of a full report from this same device -- good luck!
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Process:             ArmUIIpad [437]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D5CB9B7-D9B5-4A73-9431-C485C4124E6C/ArmUIIpad.app/ArmUIIpad
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.1 (15C153)
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4378001408
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104f30000-0000000107e80000 [ 47.3M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...app/ArmUIIpad

Triggered by Thread:  0
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Application Specific Information:
abort() called
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001824302e8 0x18240e000 + 140008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001825452f8 0x182542000 + 13048
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018239f060 0x18233c000 + 405600
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018239efc8 0x18233c000 + 405448
4   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107cfe614 0x104f30000 + 48031252
5   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c070d4 0x104f30000 + 47018196
6   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107bbf1e8 0x104f30000 + 46723560
7   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107bbdff8 0x104f30000 + 46718968
8   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107bb5fd8 0x104f30000 + 46686168
9   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000105044fc4 0x104f30000 + 1134532
10  ArmUIIpad                       0x000000010504456c 0x104f30000 + 1131884
11  ArmUIIpad                       0x00000001056033b4 0x104f30000 + 7156660
12  ArmUIIpad         <\M-b\M^@\M-&>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182430d80 0x18240e000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542eec 0x182542000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b6c 0x182542000 + 2924
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182430d80 0x18240e000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542eec 0x182542000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b6c 0x182542000 + 2924
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 3 name:  SGen worker
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001824300f0 0x18240e000 + 139504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182546ce4 0x182542000 + 19684
2   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107cccb84 0x104f30000 + 47827844
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001825442b4 0x182542000 + 8884
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182544180 0x182542000 + 8576
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b74 0x182542000 + 2932
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 4 name:  Finalizer
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018240f5a4 0x18240e000 + 5540
1   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c09024 0x104f30000 + 47026212
2   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c791b0 0x104f30000 + 47485360
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001825442b4 0x182542000 + 8884
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182544180 0x182542000 + 8576
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b74 0x182542000 + 2932
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b68 0x182542000 + 2920
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018240f568 0x18240e000 + 5480
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018240f3e0 0x18240e000 + 5088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828c6308 0x1827d8000 + 975624
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828c3ed4 0x1827d8000 + 966356
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001827e3e58 0x1827d8000 + 48728
5   Foundation                      0x0000000183219594 0x18320d000 + 50580
6   Foundation                      0x00000001832389ac 0x18320d000 + 178604
7   UIKit                           0x000000018c9cd7b8 0x18bdf0000 + 12441528
8   Foundation                      0x000000018331b0f4 0x18320d000 + 1106164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001825442b4 0x182542000 + 8884
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182544180 0x182542000 + 8576
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b74 0x182542000 + 2932
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b68 0x182542000 + 2920
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 8 name:  tid_8803
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001824300f0 0x18240e000 + 139504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182546ce4 0x182542000 + 19684
2   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107ce22f4 0x104f30000 + 47915764
3   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c6eb38 0x104f30000 + 47442744
4   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c791b0 0x104f30000 + 47485360
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001825442b4 0x182542000 + 8884
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182544180 0x182542000 + 8576
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b74 0x182542000 + 2932
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 9 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001824300f0 0x18240e000 + 139504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182546ce4 0x182542000 + 19684
2   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c6f134 0x104f30000 + 47444276
3   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c791b0 0x104f30000 + 47485360
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001825442b4 0x182542000 + 8884
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182544180 0x182542000 + 8576
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b74 0x182542000 + 2932
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 10 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001824300f0 0x18240e000 + 139504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182546ce4 0x182542000 + 19684
2   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c6f134 0x104f30000 + 47444276
3   ArmUIIpad                       0x0000000107c791b0 0x104f30000 + 47485360
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001825442b4 0x182542000 + 8884
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182544180 0x182542000 + 8576
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182542b74 0x182542000 + 2932
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[439] <Notice>: Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000033   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x00000001b5821d54
   x12: 0x00000001b5821d54  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0xfffffff00f2dd260  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b34f6b80  x21: 0x000000016aeca7b0  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b34f6c60
   x24: 0x0000000108703240  x25: 0x0000000000000002  x26: 0x000000010881d800  x27: 0x00000001056033b3
   x28: 0x0000000000010001   fp: 0x000000016aec9ce0   lr: 0x00000001825452f8
    sp: 0x000000016aec9cb0   pc: 0x00000001824302e8 cpsr: 0x00000000
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device backboardd(AttentionAwareness)[62] <Notice>:              EventStatistics.m:48  :    8168.31355:  Info: <private>since    8161.00403 (Wed Jan 17 17:20:24 2018)
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: [ArmUIIpad:437] Port death watcher fired.
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: Server invalidated <BKProcessAssertion: 0x101023810; "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.myapp.name" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&6ADC8FB2F0F4>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: Server invalidated <BKProcessAssertion: 0x10063eb10; "Suspending" (suspend:10s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&A127D87B3178>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: Process exited: <BKProcess: 0x100529ae0; ArmUIIpad; com.myapp.name; pid: 437; agency: Application; visibility: background; task: none; hostpid: 57>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device powerd[39] <Notice>: Process assertiond.68 Released SystemIsActive "ArmUIIpad:437:57-5D0FDB42-E7B1-4091-AC4C-6ADC8FB2F0F4 [FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.myapp.name] [0x101023810]" age:00:00:00  id:51539641844 [System: SysAct]
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: [ArmUIIpad:437] Invalidating...
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: Releasing PowerAssertion on ArmUIIpad:437 from invalidate
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: Client relinquished <BKProcessAssertion: 0x101023810; "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.myapp.name" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&6ADC8FB2F0F4>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: Client relinquished <BKProcessAssertion: 0x10063eb10; "Suspending" (suspend:10s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&A127D87B3178>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: [ArmUIIpad:437] dump all assertions HWM:3 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x101023810; "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.myapp.name" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&6ADC8FB2F0F4> [active]
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x10063eb10; "Suspending" (suspend:10s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&A127D87B3178> [active]
}
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: [ArmUIIpad:437] Ignoring assertion remove, because we are terminated or pending termination
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: [ArmUIIpad:437] Ignoring assertion remove, because we are terminated or pending termination
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device awdd[90] <Notice>: loc.mgr:#N Marking location used by calling current location
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device awdd(CoreLocation)[90] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLLocationManager", "event":"activity", "_cmd":"location", "self":"0x105204c40"}
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device locationd[65] <Notice>: {"msg":"client getting effective client name", "clientName":"\134/System\134/Library\134/PrivateFrameworks\134/WirelessDiagnostics.framework\134/Support\134/awdd", "bundleId":"", "bundlePath":"\134/System\134/Library\134/PrivateFrameworks\134/WirelessDiagnostics.framework"}
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device assertiond[68] <Notice>: [ArmUIIpad:437] Got exit context: <BKSProcessExitContext: 0x1010210f0; reason: (none)>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] <Notice>: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x137033720; ArmUIIpad (com.myapp.name); pid: 437> exited.
```

Looks like there is some kind of crash but I'm not sure what exactly is happening. All I see is:

```
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] <Notice>: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x137033720; ArmUIIpad (com.myapp.name); pid: 437> exited.
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] <Notice>: [FBProcessManager] Removing: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x137033720; ArmUIIpad (com.myapp.name); pid: -1>
Jan 17 17:20:31 iPad-Device SpringBoard[57] <Notice>: Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x137033720; ArmUIIpad (com.myapp.name); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x1c884d1a0; exitReason: (none); terminationReason: (none)> {
    stateAtExit = <FBProcessState: 0x1c882e360; pid: 437; taskState: Not Running; visibility: Unknown>;
}
```

iPad that crashes: iPad7,4 iOS 11.2.1

iPad that doesn't crash but doesn't attach: iPad3,4 iOS 10.3.3

Simulator I use mostly: iPad (5th generation) 11.2

Can you please help me to find out what's the problem?

Comment: I think whether it is the problem of running memory. Real device's memory is different from simulator. Do you run some code causing out of memory?

Comment: I thought of that but there are older versions that used to run normally (like just two weeks ago) and now crash on launch. Besides, there's an older device that obviously has less memory but runs app without crashing (the debugger stops though). There's just auth screen to be loaded after launch, no heavy downloading or calculations, no idea what could cause OOM on launch

Comment: `Symbolication may be possible by manually cleaning up and including the Binary Image section of a full report from this same device -- good luck!` Talk about kicking you while you're down.